# SignalR package installing Error

Tags: c#, asp.net, signalr, package, nuget-package

this is how it looks like when I try to install the singalr package from the NuGet ...

```
Could not install package 'Microsoft.Owin.Security 2.1.0'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETFr
amework,Version=v4.0', but the package does not contain any assembly references that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact 
the package author.
```

I've tried to find the 1.1.3 version but there is no existing version ... would be thankful for any helpful tips for correcting the error

Comment: what version of nuget do you have installed?

Comment: @HwasooLee 2.8.60318.667 that version

Comment: Version 1.1.3 of SignalR has been unlisted from NuGet. https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR/1.1.3

Comment: It says that the package `Microsoft.Owin.Security 2.1.0` doesn't support your current .Net framework version which is 4.0

Comment: @James Thanks the link was useful :)

Comment: Have a look at the following article. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28807273/installing-asp-net-signalr-error-while-installing